# how to simulate slow update sql?

Tags: mysql

DBA told me there are some slow sql I should to optimize, 
[image]

and actually there are 10 same update sql and the longest time is 56 seconds.

The business logic of this sql is that, if user wins an award , should decrease one stock of this award.

I think it is caused by high concurrent, only in this case it exist lock competion. Then I decided to repropduce it in my local environment, I let many thread to execute update operation simultaneously, but I cannot reproduce the above slow sql, below is my experiment result:

```
thred count|100|500|1000|2000
-----|-----|-----|-----|-----
took time(ms)|149|490|1064|1996
```

even 2000 update sql to execute concurrently, it only need `1996`ms to execute all. So how to reprduce these slow sql?

My code is like this

```
@Test
public void test_concurrent_update() throws InterruptedException {
    int nThreads = 50; //thread count

    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);
    final CountDownLatch startLatch = new CountDownLatch(nThreads);
    final CountDownLatch endLatch = new CountDownLatch(nThreads);
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
        pool.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startLatch.countDown(); // let all threads concurrently execute update operation
                try { startLatch.await(); } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                mapper.updateAwardStock(); // reduce stock by mybatis
                endLatch.countDown();
                System.out.printf("%s down%n",Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        });
    }

    endLatch.await(); // wait for all threads are finished executing
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.printf("%d threads concurrent update stock took time: %d(ms)%n",nThreads,(endTime-startTime));

}

@Update("update award_stock set stock = stock-1 where award_id = 1 and  stock>0 limit 1")
void updateAwardStock();
```

Comment: take a look at that screen shot you posted. Please see if you can read it. Why don't you post it as text

Comment: The slowness in the query suggests that there is no combined index on (award_id,stock).  Concurrency, *per se*, should not actually be the underlying problem, here... and you seem to have proven this with your code.  Large tables without the appropriate indexes would be a much more likely cause, and concurrency would exaggerate the problem because of the work requires to do the necessary scans.

Comment: till now this table only have `2461` rows and `award_id` is key